# textures and vertex arrays with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Basically what I'd like to do is make textured NGONS. I also want to use a tesselator (GLU) to make concave and multicontour objects.

I was wondering how the texture comes into play though. I think that the tesselator will return verticies so I will add these to my array, that's fine. But my vertex array will contain more than one polygon object so then how can I tell it when to bind the texture like in immediate mode? Right now I feel stuck with one call to bind.

How can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`, you'll have to draw your vertices in pieces, one piece per texture. The same texture is used for the entire call. (These calls are like a potentially more efficient version of submitting the same data by hand within `glBegin` and `glEnd`, and you can't change texture inside a `glBegin`...`glEnd` block, either.)

You could alternatively stick with `glBegin` and `glEnd`, and use `glArrayElement` to submit vertices whose attributes are taken out of the vertex arrays.